# Regex to match words between underscores after second occurence of underscore

Tags: c#, regex

so i would like to get words between underscores after second occurence of underscore

this is my string

`ABC_BC_BE08_C1000004_0124`

I've assembled this expresion

`(?<=_)[^_]+`

well it matches what i need but only skips the first word since there is no underscore before it. I would like it to skip ABC and BC and just get the last three strings, i've tried messing around but i am stuck and cant make it work. Thanks!

Comment: So, the output should be `BE08_C1000004_0124`? Or `['BE08','C1000004','0124']`?

Comment: nah just the strings without the underscore, [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MSolyV/1) so the way it matches now is good but i want it to skip the first two words ABC and BC

Edit: so `['BE08','C1000004','0124']`

Comment: `'0124'` is not *between* underscores. Be precise!

Comment: Get an array using `split("_+")`. Why go through the regex match route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a non-regex approach here with `Split` and `Skip`:

```cs
var text = "ABC_BC_BE08_C1000004_0124";
var result = text.Split('_').Skip(2);
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
BE08
C1000004
0124
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/jjO284).

With regex, you can use

```cs
var result = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=^(?:[^_]*_){2,})[^_]+").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%28%3F%3A%5B%5E_%5D*_%29%7B2%2C%7D%29%5B%5E_%5D%2B&i=ABC_BC_BE08_C1000004_0124) and the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/DBXVfM). The regex matches

- `(?<=^(?:[^_]*_){2,})` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that matches the following patterns immediately to the left of the current location:

  - `^` - start of string
  - `(?:[^_]*_){2,}` - two or more (`{2,}`) sequences of any zero or more chars other than `_` (`[^_]*`) and then a `_` char
- `[^_]+` - one or more chars other than `_`

Answer (score 3):

Usign .NET there is also a [captures collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capturecollection?view=net-6.0) that you might use with a regex and a repeated catpure group.

```
^[^_]*_[^_]*(?:_([^_]+))+
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[^_]*_[^_]*` Match any char except an `_`, match `_` and again any char except `_`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `_([^_]+)` Match `_` and capture 1 or more times any char except `_` in **group 1**
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1 or more times

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5e_%5d*_%5b%5e_%5d*%28%3f%3a_%28%5b%5e_%5d%2b%29%29%2b&i=ABC_BC_BE08_C1000004_0124) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/MiPTma)

For example:

```
var pattern = @"^[^_]*_[^_]*(?:_([^_]+))+";
var str = "ABC_BC_BE08_C1000004_0124";
var strings = Regex.Match(str, pattern).Groups[1].Captures.Select(c => c.Value);

foreach (String s in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Output

```
BE08
C1000004
0124
```

[image]

If you want to match only word characters in between the underscores, another option for a pattern could be using a negated character class `[^\W_]` excluding the underscore from the word characters in between:

```
^[^\W_]*_[^\W_]*(?:_([^\W_]+))+
```

Comment: CapturekCollection is the only viable regex method in this case. Somebody is deleting my comments. Why is that ?

Comment: @sln Hi there, the comments can be flagged or removed by a moderator I think. Why I am not sure, not long ago comments were remove very fast but that was a short period.

Comment: Thank you. I had a comment deleted above that was technical with examples and important. I take exception to that.

Comment: Yeah, this was my comment I put there which apparently is not allowed:  Yes, a lookbehind can be done but it is not viable due to the included anchor.
`(?<=^(?:[^_]*_){2,})` represents an _infinite series summation 1 + 2 + 3 + ... n = n(n+1)/2_ so for n = 200 there is 20,100 matches of segments to match just 200.
If you put capture groups around the assertion the series is revealed https://regex101.com/r/9tS1zO/1 Maybe SO considers this a personal attack as opposed to technical information.